# using c# parse and iterate through json object to address each field

Tags: c#, json

This is a very simple question but can't seem to find a direct answer. I read in a single JSON object. I then want to parse it and be able to directly address a token or a value and then format it for writing a file output, which I will use in another application. I am using C# and the Newtonsoft library.

My code:

```
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(re);
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Value != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", "This is the value <Tags>:  " + reader.Value);
}
```

How can I address each line? for example, desc and then Gets a reference to the game world. This must be so commoplace.

Thanks,

johnh

Comment: please share with us reader.Value

Answer (score 4):

Use the `JArray` and `JObject` objects instead, like this:

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("YourJSONFilePath");
var objects = JArray.Parse(json);

foreach(JObject root in objects)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<String, JToken> tag in root)
    {
        var tagName = tag.Key;
        Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", "This is the value <Tags>:  " + tagName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given a `JToken token`:

```
if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
{
    foreach (var pair in token as JObject)
    {
        string name = pair.Key;
        JToken child = pair.Value;
        //do something with the JSON properties
    }
}
else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    foreach (var child in token.Children())
    {
        //do something with the JSON array items
    }
}
else
{
    //do something with a JSON value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the properties of the reader as it's reading the string. Especially at the TokenType and Value properties. If you really need to read it sequentially that's the way to go. TokenType will be, in order, StartObject, PropertyName, String etc. depending on the node being read. Basically each time you see a PropertyName, the next one will be the property value.

Take note that you'd probably be better off using other techniques but it all depends.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this thread is a bit old... However, @Karl Anderson, your answer was helpful. I just added a little bit to it which was way better than the 3 or 4 nested foreach loops that I had going on... see code below. Thank you for the help!

```
JArray jsonResponse = JArray.Parse(content);
Debug.WriteLine("\n\njsonResponse: \n" + jsonResponse);

foreach (JObject root in jsonResponse)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> tag in root)
    {
        var tagName = tag.Key;
        var variable = tag.Value;
        Debug.WriteLine("Key: " + tagName + "  Value: " + variable);
    }
}
```